# Como receber no email informações somadas no site html?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

já tentei de muitas maneiras mas não tive sucesso em receber no email as informações somadas pelo cliente.
Vou resumir já consegui o código, o cliente acessa o site clica nos respectivos itens daí e feito a soma porém não consigo receber no email essas informações criadas...

```
       function salvaJogo(tipo) {
             $.post("/game/includes/enviaEmail.php", {

                  jogo: $.cookie("jogo"),
                    jogo1: $.cookie("jogo1"),
                    hd: $.cookie('hd'),
                    item_adicional: $.cookie("item_adicional"),
                    itens: item_adicional,
                    jogo: $.cookie("jogo"),
                    jogo_g: $.cookie("jogo_g")
                }, function (data) {
                    if (data == 'ok') {
                        $('#aguarde').hide();
                        $('#meio .conteudo').css('opacity', 1);

                        var notification = new NotificationFx({
                            message: '<div class="icone_42 icone_ok"></div><p>Sucesso! Seu orçamento foi enviado para nossa equipe. Aguarde nosso contato.</p>',
                            layout: 'attached',
                            wrapper: document.getElementById("meio"),
                            effect: 'bouncyflip',
                            ttl: 10000,
                            type: 'notice',
                            onClose: function () {
                                //fechou
                            }
                        });
                        notification.show();
                        window.location.href = "#meio";

                        //voltarPrincipal();
                    } else {
                        $('#aguarde').hide();
                        $('#meio .conteudo').css('opacity', 1);

                        var notification = new NotificationFx({
                            message: '<div class="icone_42 icone_alerta"></div><p>Infelizmente ocorreu um erro. Volte mais tarde.</p>',
                            layout: 'attached',
                            wrapper: document.getElementById("meio"),
                            effect: 'bouncyflip',
                            ttl: 10000,
                            type: 'notice',
                            onClose: function () {
                                //fechou
                            }
                        });
                        notification.show();
                        window.location.href = "#meio";

                        voltarPrincipal();
                        console.log('retorno: ' + data);
                    }
```

enviaEmail.php foi o arquivo que tentei criar para receber no email

codigo que já tenho pronto está acima algumas linhas.
Se alguém puder me dar uma força ficarei muito grato!

Comment: O problema está no JavaScript ou no arquivo PHP que vc criou para enviar o email? Se o problema for no PHP, inclua na pergunta o código do PHP tb.

Comment: Boa noite Sam espero muito que vc me ajude onde estou errando adciono um var_dump?

Comment: Tem que verificar... está entrando no `if (data == 'ok') {`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {

    //Variaveis de POST, Alterar somente se necessário 
    //====================================================

  $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade']; 
  $hd_camisa = $_POST['hd_camisa'];
  $hd_calcao = $_POST['hd_calcao'];
  $hd_meiao = $_POST['hd_meiao'];
  $nome = $_POST['nome']; 
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $telefone = $_POST['telefone']; 
  $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
  $estado = $_POST['estado'];
  $comentarios = $_POST['comentarios'];
  $pacote = $_POST['pacote'];
  $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];  
  $hd_calcao = $_POST['hd_calcao'];
  $hd_calcao = $_POST['hd_calcao'];
  $quantidade_goleiro = $_POST['quantidade_goleiro'];
  $hd_camisa_goleiro = $_POST['hd_camisa_goleiro'];
  $hd_meiao_goleiro = $_POST['hd_meiao_goleiro'];
  $jogo = $_POST['jogo'];
  $jogo_goleiro = $_POST['jogo_goleiro'];
  hd_calcao_goleiro = $_POST['hd_calcao_goleiro'];
  $item_adicional = $_POST['item_adicional'];
  $jogo = $_POST['jogo'];
  $jogo_goleiro = $_POST['jogo_goleiro'];
    //====================================================

    //REMETENTE --> ESTE EMAIL TEM QUE SER VALIDO DO DOMINIO
    //==================================================== 
    $email_remetente = "BORUTO.NPG@.com"; // deve ser uma conta de email do seu dominio 
    //====================================================

    //Configurações do email, ajustar conforme necessidade
    //==================================================== 
    $email_destinatario = "BORUTO.NPG@gmail.com"; // pode ser qualquer email que receberá as mensagens
    $email_reply = "$email"; 
    $email_assunto = "Menssagem do site"; // Este será o assunto da mensagem
    //====================================================

    //Monta o Corpo da Mensagem
    //====================================================

  $email_conteudo .= "Quantidade = $quantidade \n"; 
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_camisa = $hd_camisa \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_calcao = $hd_calcao \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_meiao = $hd_meiao \n";
  $email_conteudo = "Nome = $nome \n"; 
  $email_conteudo .= "Email = $email \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Telefone = $telefone \n"; 
  $email_conteudo .= "Cidade = $cidade \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Estado = $estado \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Comentarios = $comentarios \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Pacote =$pacote \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Quantidade = $quantidade \n";  
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_calcao = $hd_calcao \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_calcao = $hd_calcao \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Quantidade_goleiro = $quantidade_goleiro \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_camisa_goleiro = $hd_camisa_goleiro \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_meiao_goleiro = $hd_meiao_goleiro \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Jogo = $jogo \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Jogo_goleiro = $jogo_goleiro \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Hd_calcao_goleiro = $hd_calcao_goleiro \n"; 
  $email_conteudo .= "Item_adicional = $item_adicional \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Jogo = $jogo \n";
  $email_conteudo .= "Jogo_goleiro = $jogo_goleiro \n";          



    //====================================================

    //Seta os Headers (Alterar somente caso necessario) 
    //==================================================== 
    $email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $email_remetente", "Reply-To: $email_reply", "Return-Path: $email_remetente","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );
    //====================================================

    //Enviando o email 
    //==================================================== 
    if (mail ($email_destinatario, $email_assunto, nl2br($email_conteudo), $email_headers)){ 
                    echo "</b>sucesso! Seu orÃ§amento foi enviado para nossa equipe. Aguarde nosso contato.</b>"; 
                    } 
            else{ 
                    echo "</b>Falha no envio do E-Mail!</b>"; } 
    //====================================================
} 
?>
```